# I want to add some UI elements when user press the button like shape editor in maya

Tags: python, function, user-interface, button, maya

I want to add some UI elements when the user presses the button, something like a shape editor in Maya, this code just add a number, for now, I don't know how to receive variable from this function after pressing a button so I use a global variable, this code is working fine, but it's nice to do it without using a global variable, is there a way?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEbi8.png)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
a =10

def defaultButtonPush():
  global a
  a=a+1
  print a

cmds.window( width=150 )
cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
cmds.button( label='Button 1', command="defaultButtonPush()") 
cmds.showWindow()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class to create your UI. With a class you can keep all needed data inside the class an you can access it easily. It works like this in a simple form:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class MyUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.buildUI()
        
    def pressButtonCallback(self, arg):
        self.value += 1
        print(self.value)
        
    def buildUI(self):
        cmds.window( width=150 )
        cmds.columnLayout( adjustableColumn=True )
        cmds.button( label='Button 1', command=self.pressButtonCallback) 
        cmds.showWindow()

c = MyUI()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I also ask this question in CGtalk I send the link there.